# Server not starting due to haystack error

Tags: django, django-haystack

I have just installed haystack and whoosh in my django project.I was following an online tutorial.however when i start server it gives me the following error "no module named apps".what could i be doing wrong ?

**Error message in cmd:**

[image: Screenshot of error message in cmd]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem related to your django version. Haystack doesn't work with django 1.9

**UPDATE**
django haystack 2.5 is out. It work's with django 1.9

Comment: is there any other alternative search app i can use ?

Comment: Not that i know of. You can install haystack their git repo directly from https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack